# offbeat titles in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSb4H.png)

["raw" csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cui5j.png)

Hello
I have a beginner problem, my titles are not in front of the right columns, and I wonder if there is a recipe to solve the problem easily.
Maybe the solution is simple to find or you have to make a loop, I'm a beginner I'm a little lost

here the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

df = pd.read_csv("USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv")
#the output dataframe is on the top
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you include your code where you create your dataframe?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv")

Comment: Please add the code by editing your question, this makes it more readable and easier for people to get all the information. If possible also add your current output (and the code that created it) as well as the expected output.

Comment: tell me if anything is missing

Comment: Can you add the first couple of lines of your csv file as text in your question? It should include the line with the titles and 2-5 lines of data.

Comment: you should decorate your code with backticks ( \` ) for it to appear `like this`. This will also help with formatting. Check the guide on single and triple backticks.

Comment: which part of the code should I decorate please?

Comment: @osef I have edited your question. Please take a look at my usage of the backticks for future questions. :)

Comment: @YPOC i'am sorry i don t see any backticks in your edit

Comment: You can try `df = pd.read_csv("USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv", index_col=False)` but that won't fix everything. You'll probably loose the right part of the dataset. Assuming the comma (`,`) is the delimiter, the csv seems to be messed up (*11 columns as a header vs. 19 fields in each row*).

Comment: @Timeless thank you very much, that's the solution I'm going to keep until I hear from my broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot fix the input data in the csv, you can rename the headers after reading in the csv file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv")
new_headers = ["Date", "Time", "OpenBid", "HighBid", ...]  # Complete with all your header names
df.columns = new_headers
```

If you have fewer headers than data columns, the last few columns will not have a header, but the beginning of your dataframe will now be correctly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your header doesn't match the data. In the header there are fewer names than you have columns. Pandas assumes the header names are for the last columns, therefore leaving the first few columns unnamed. These columns then become a `MultiIndex` (you probably don't want to deal with that yet).

Assumedly you want to have these names for the first few columns. You could achieve this with `df = pd.read_csv("USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv", usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10])`, however this is very hacky and will simply not load the last columns.

Another way is to specify the header yourself. One way is

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "USDJPY_m1_BidAndAsk.csv",
    header = 0,
    names = ["date","time","col1","col2",...,"last_col"]
)
```

perhaps in conjuction with `usecols`, should you not need all columns. Make sure to specify exactly as many column names as you are importing.

However you are better off when you actually fix your input data.

Comment: Unfortunately this data comes from my broker, and I don't really have any control over the flows (I'll ask anyway).

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

thanks @YPOC